# On blur issues in jquery..Need focus to change out of text box..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, javascript-remoting

I have a VF page..I have a button open pop up..on click of that button i am opening a pop up using output panel and css...using the code something like this..

**LINK**
http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-modal-dialog-box/

On that pop up i am using autocomplete using VF remoting and a confirm button on that popup..My problem is i am using blur event whenever i type some thing in that autocomplete text box i am selecting a autocomplete record and on onblur event calling a method but the curser remains in that text box.So when i click a  confirm button onblur event is again called calling the controller method.

I want the curser to move out of the textbox after onblur event ..??
I need some jquery/javascript code...

```
close: function(){
      j$(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).blur();
   }
```

Please help i am stuck with this issue...for 3 days...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move out of the textbox, you'll need to give the focus to another element on the page - for example, an input or a button.

To apply focus to an element using JQuery, you would simply execute the .focus() method after the selector, so if the element has the id 'test', you would use:

```
j$('#test').focus();
```